# How to search a specific value in all tables (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, grep, string-matching

Is it possible to search **every column of every table** for a particular value in PostgreSQL?

A similar question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle) for Oracle.

Comment: No, just the simplest way to find a specific value in all fields/tables.

Comment: So you don't want to use an external tool?

Comment: If it's the simplest way => ok for an external tool :-)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

How about dumping the contents of the database, then using `grep`?

```
$ pg_dump --data-only --inserts -U postgres your-db-name > a.tmp
$ grep United a.tmp
INSERT INTO countries VALUES ('US', 'United States');
INSERT INTO countries VALUES ('GB', 'United Kingdom');
```

The same utility, pg_dump, can include column names in the output. Just change `--inserts` to `--column-inserts`. That way you can search for specific column names, too. But if I were looking for column names, I'd probably dump the schema instead of the data.

```
$ pg_dump --data-only --column-inserts -U postgres your-db-name > a.tmp
$ grep country_code a.tmp
INSERT INTO countries (iso_country_code, iso_country_name) VALUES ('US', 'United  States');
INSERT INTO countries (iso_country_code, iso_country_name) VALUES ('GB', 'United Kingdom');
```

Comment: +1 free and simple. And if you want structure pg_dump can do that too. Also if grep isn't your thing use what ever file content searching tool you want on the dumped out structures and/or data.

Comment: If you want to grep text data (which is typically encoded in more recent versions of postgres), you may need to `ALTER DATABASE your_db_name SET bytea_output = 'escape';` on the database (or a copy thereof) before dumping it. (I'm not seeing a way to specify this just for a `pg_dump` command.)

Comment: can you explain in detail .. ? How to search string 'ABC' into all tables ?

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ you can just right-click your db and select "Dump with 'pg_dump'" or "Dump data to file(s)"

Comment: How is this a valid solution for any database that's sufficiently large that you can't dump it to your disk?

Comment: @GovindParmar: That wasn't the OP's question. With cloud services nowadays, you can provision many terabytes of disk space if you need it. The real issue here is not knowing what the value you're looking for represents. Say you're looking for "CA" and, according to the question, you don't even know what table it's in. You don't know whether it's a city, a state code, a country code, a person's nickname, etc. *That's* the real problem.

Comment: It's also useful to add `--disable-triggers` flag

Comment: @kapandron: The `--disable-triggers` flag isn't really useful if you're just searching a dump for values. It's useful only when you're *restoring* from a dump. [Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 126):

Here's a **pl/pgsql function** that locates records where any column contains a specific value.
It takes as arguments the value to search in text format, an array of table names to search into (defaults to all tables) and an array of schema names (defaults all schema names).

It returns a table structure with schema, name of table, name of column and pseudo-column `ctid` (non-durable physical location of the row in the table, see [System Columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html))

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{}'
)
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
  FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
        JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
          (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
        JOIN information_schema.table_privileges p ON
          (t.table_name=p.table_name AND t.table_schema=p.table_schema
              AND p.privilege_type='SELECT')
        JOIN information_schema.schemata s ON
          (s.schema_name=t.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND (c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema) OR haystack_schema='{}')
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
    FOR rowctid IN
      EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
      )
    LOOP
      -- uncomment next line to get some progress report
      -- RAISE NOTICE 'hit in %.%', schemaname, tablename;
      RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

See also the [**version on github**](https://github.com/dverite/postgresql-functions/tree/master/global_search) based on the same principle but adding some speed and reporting improvements.

Examples of use in a test database:

- Search in all tables within public schema:

```
select * from search_columns('foobar');
 schemaname | tablename | columnname | rowctid 
------------+-----------+------------+---------
 public     | s3        | usename    | (0,11)
 public     | s2        | relname    | (7,29)
 public     | w         | body       | (0,2)
(3 rows)
```

- Search in a specific table:

```
 select * from search_columns('foobar','{w}');
 schemaname | tablename | columnname | rowctid 
------------+-----------+------------+---------
 public     | w         | body       | (0,2)
(1 row)
```

- Search in a subset of tables obtained from a select:

```
select * from search_columns('foobar', array(select table_name::name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 's%'), array['public']);
 schemaname | tablename | columnname | rowctid 
------------+-----------+------------+---------
 public     | s2        | relname    | (7,29)
 public     | s3        | usename    | (0,11)
(2 rows)
```

- Get a result row with the corresponding base table and and ctid:

```
select * from public.w where ctid='(0,2)';
 title |  body  |         tsv         
-------+--------+---------------------
 toto  | foobar | 'foobar':2 'toto':1
```

### Variants

- To test against a regular expression instead of strict equality, like grep, this part of the query:

  `SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L`

  may be changed to:

  `SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text) ~ %L`
- For case insensitive comparisons, you could write:

  `SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE lower(cast(%I as text)) = lower(%L)`

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "default"
LINE 3:     haystack_tables name[] default '{}' (Using PostgreSQL 8.2.17 and cannot upgrade)

Comment: @Henno: yes it requires PG-9.1. Edited now to make that explicit. To use it with older versions, you'll have to adapt it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't feel my skills + time is sufficient for that... I tried googling for postgresql function default argument but I'm not even sure if the problem is name[] or the default keyword.

Comment: @Henno: I'm sure it's _default_ and the 2nd problem will be _format()_ which appeared in 9.1. What you may do is post a question linking to this one and asking how to convert that to 8.2. Also maybe you don't need these _haystack*_ parameters if you need to search in every schema/every table.

Comment: @DanielVérité I am using regular expression and updated the query as metnioned below but still I am not able to search with case insensitive. am I doing wrong in this query ?  SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I AS t WHERE lower(cast(t.* as text)) ~ lower(%L)

Comment: @Rajendra_Prasad: the regular expression operator has a case insensitive variant: `~*` more adequate than lower(). But anyway the `t.*` is not part of the above answer. Searching column by column is not the same as searching the row as a value because of the column separators.

Comment: This only returns one row per schema-table-column.

Comment: @theGtknerd: thanks for the heads up, the function is now **updated to return one row per hit**. I don't remember if the previous behavior was intentional, but one can simply append `LIMIT 1` to the search query to get it back if needed.

Comment: @DanielVérité Sorry I submitted that edit that was really more like an addition. I regretted it after. I'm glad it prompted you to update the one row per hit thing, and you made what I was trying to do cleaner as well. Thank you for maintaining your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution works perfectly for me. I had to locate a table in a list of more than 1000 tables which contains a specific url. You saved my day!.

Comment: I cannot search. https://github.com/dverite/postgresql-functions/issues/2 please help me. this is my database and my query https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SEi7uj16uAOhfGdN8vc-0rMHP9DgyJrM?usp=sharing I search keyword *cuoi_nam*

Answer (score 20):

> to search every column of every table for a particular value

Assuming:

- Find any row with any column ***containing*** the given value in its text representation - as opposed to *equaling* the given value.
- Return the table name (`regclass`) and the tuple ID (`ctid`), because that's simplest. (You can easily adapt to return whatever you want.)

Here is a dead simple, fast, and slightly dirty way:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_whole_db(_like_pattern text, _schema text)
  RETURNS TABLE(_tbl regclass, _ctid tid)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN
      SELECT c.oid::regclass
      FROM   pg_class c
      JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = relnamespace
      WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'                           -- only tables
      AND    n.nspname !~ '^(pg_|information_schema)'  -- exclude system schemas
      AND   (n.nspname = _schema OR _schema IS NULL)
      ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
         'SELECT $1, ctid FROM %s t WHERE t::text ~~ %L'
       , _tbl, '%' || _like_pattern || '%')
      USING _tbl;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

If no schema is specified, the whole DB is searched: (System schemas are always excluded.)

```
SELECT * FROM search_whole_db('mypattern');
```

For a given schema only:

```
SELECT * FROM search_whole_db('mypattern', 'myschema');
```

Provide the search pattern without enclosing `%`.
You may want to escape special characters in the pattern. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

**Why "slightly dirty"?**

If separators and decorators for the row in `text` representation can be part of the search pattern, there can be false positives. Special characters are:

- column separator: `,` by default
- whole row is enclosed in parentheses:`()`
- some values are enclosed in double quotes `"`
- `\` may be added as escape char

Plus, the text representation of some columns may depend on local settings - but that ambiguity is inherent to the question, not just to my solution.

Each qualifying row is returned ***once*** only, even when it matches multiple times (as opposed to other answers here).

Searching the whole DB typically ***takes a long time to finish***. You might want to restrict to certain schemas / tables (or even columns) like demonstrated in other answers. Or add notices and a progress indicator, also demonstrated in another answer.

The `regclass` object identifier type is represented as table name, schema-qualified where necessary to disambiguate according to the current `search_path`:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [Find the referenced table name using table, field and schema name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618312/find-the-referenced-table-name-using-table-field-and-schema-name/15625024#15625024)

What is the `ctid`?

- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66007/3684)

You might want to escape characters with special meaning in the search pattern. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

Comment: This great solution is even better with lower() -  'SELECT $1, ctid FROM %s t WHERE lower(t::text) ~~ lower(%L)'

Comment: I what if I wanted to specify the schema. How might I change the function to reflect this?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch: I added a function parameter for that.

Answer (score 13):

There is a way to achieve this without creating a function or using an external tool. By using Postgres' `query_to_xml()` function that can dynamically run a query inside another query, it's possible to search a text across many tables. This is based on my answer [to retrieve the rowcount for all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225/330315):

To search for the string `foo` across all tables in a schema, the following can be used:

```
with found_rows as (
  select format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name) as table_name,
         query_to_xml(format('select to_jsonb(t) as table_row 
                              from %I.%I as t 
                              where t::text like ''%%foo%%'' ', table_schema, table_name), 
                      true, false, '') as table_rows
  from information_schema.tables 
  where table_schema = 'public'
)
select table_name, x.table_row
from found_rows f
  left join xmltable('//table/row' 
                     passing table_rows
                       columns
                         table_row text path 'table_row') as x on true
```

Note that the use of `xmltable` requires Postgres 10 or newer. For older Postgres version, this can be also done using xpath().

```
with found_rows as (
  select format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name) as table_name,
         query_to_xml(format('select to_jsonb(t) as table_row 
                              from %I.%I as t 
                              where t::text like ''%%foo%%'' ', table_schema, table_name), 
                      true, false, '') as table_rows
  from information_schema.tables 
  where table_schema = 'public'
)
select table_name, x.table_row
from found_rows f
   cross join unnest(xpath('/table/row/table_row/text()', table_rows)) as r(data)
```

The common table expression (`WITH ...`) is only used for convenience. It loops through all tables in the `public` schema. For each table the following query is run through the `query_to_xml()` function:

```
select to_jsonb(t)
from some_table t
where t::text like '%foo%';
```

The where clause is used to make sure the expensive generation of XML content is only done for rows that contain the search string. This might return something like this:

```xml
<table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
  <table_row>{"id": 42, "some_column": "foobar"}</table_row>
</row>
</table>
```

The conversion of the complete row to `jsonb` is done, so that in the result one could see which value belongs to which column.

The above might return something like this:

```
table_name   |   table_row
-------------+----------------------------------------
public.foo   |  {"id": 1, "some_column": "foobar"}
public.bar   |  {"id": 42, "another_column": "barfoo"}
```

[Online example for Postgres 10+](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=650d8630432ab161310d81c3af5d6657)

[Online example for older Postgres versions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d36f3d68154864556ba821ccbd8ac93e)

Comment: I'm trying to run the code for older PostgreSQL versions and I am getting the following error `ERROR: 42883: function format("unknown", information_schema.sql_identifier, information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist`

Comment: You probably need to cast them: `format('%I.%I', table_schema::text, table_name::text)`

Comment: Ok, done that, now I have `ERROR: 42883: function format("unknown", character varying, character varying) does not exist`

Comment: Then many your Postgres version is so old, that id doesn't even have the `format()` function

Comment: I think Redshift is based on 8.3?

Comment: As I said: ***so*** old that it doesn't even have a `format()` function. There is no way you can adapt this to Redshift

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using IntelliJ add your DB to Database view then right click on databases and select full text search, it will list all tables and all fields for your specific text.

Comment: this feature is not available if you are using IntelliJ community edition

Answer (score 7):

Without storing a new procedure you can use a code block and execute to obtain a table of occurences. You can filter results by schema, table or column name.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  value int := 0;
  sql text := 'The constructed select statement';
  rec1 record;
  rec2 record;
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _x;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _x (
    schema_name text, 
    table_name text, 
    column_name text,
    found text
  );
  FOR rec1 IN 
        SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name <> '_x'
                AND UPPER(column_name) LIKE UPPER('%%')                  
                AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog'
                AND table_schema <> 'information_schema'
                AND data_type IN ('character varying', 'text', 'character', 'char', 'varchar')
        LOOP
    sql := concat('SELECT ', rec1."column_name", ' AS "found" FROM ',rec1."table_schema" , '.',rec1."table_name" , ' WHERE UPPER(',rec1."column_name" , ') LIKE UPPER(''','%my_substring_to_find_goes_here%' , ''')');
    RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;
    BEGIN
        FOR rec2 IN EXECUTE sql LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;
            INSERT INTO _x VALUES (rec1."table_schema", rec1."table_name", rec1."column_name", rec2."found");
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    END;
  END LOOP;
  END; $$;

SELECT * FROM _x;
```

Comment: Where do you specify the search string?  Or is this just dumping the entire DB, table by table?

Comment: I did not created a parameter for the string. You can either hardcode it and run it direcly as a block or create a stored procedure from it. In any case, your string to search goes here between the two percent signs: WHERE UPPER(',rec1."column_name" , ') LIKE UPPER(''','%%' , ''')

Answer (score 5):

And if someone think it could help. Here is @Daniel Vérité's function, with another param that accept names of columns that can be used in search. This way it decrease the time of processing. At least in my test it reduced a lot.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_columns name[] default '{}',
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{public}'
)
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
  FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
      JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
        (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema)
        AND (c.column_name=ANY(haystack_columns) OR haystack_columns='{}')
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
    ) INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid is not null THEN
      RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Bellow is an example of usage of the search_function created above.

```
SELECT * FROM search_columns('86192700'
    , array(SELECT DISTINCT a.column_name::name FROM information_schema.columns AS a
            INNER JOIN information_schema.tables as b ON (b.table_catalog = a.table_catalog AND b.table_schema = a.table_schema AND b.table_name = a.table_name)
        WHERE 
            a.column_name iLIKE '%cep%' 
            AND b.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND b.table_schema = 'public'
    )

    , array(SELECT b.table_name::name FROM information_schema.columns AS a
            INNER JOIN information_schema.tables as b ON (b.table_catalog = a.table_catalog AND b.table_schema = a.table_schema AND b.table_name = a.table_name)
        WHERE 
            a.column_name iLIKE '%cep%' 
            AND b.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND b.table_schema = 'public')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's @Daniel Vérité's function with progress reporting functionality.
It reports progress in three ways:

1. by RAISE NOTICE;
2. by decreasing value of supplied {progress_seq} sequence from
   {total number of colums to search in} down to 0;
3. by writing the progress along with found tables into text file,
   located in c:\windows\temp\{progress_seq}.txt.

_

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{public}',
    progress_seq text default NULL
)
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
DECLARE
currenttable text;
columnscount integer;
foundintables text[];
foundincolumns text[];
begin
currenttable='';
columnscount = (SELECT count(1)
      FROM information_schema.columns c
      JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
        (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema)
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE')::integer;
PERFORM setval(progress_seq::regclass, columnscount);

  FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
      JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
        (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema)
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
    ) INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid is not null THEN
      RETURN NEXT;
      foundintables = foundintables || tablename;
      foundincolumns = foundincolumns || columnname;
      RAISE NOTICE 'FOUND! %, %, %, %', schemaname,tablename,columnname, rowctid;
    END IF;
         IF (progress_seq IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        PERFORM nextval(progress_seq::regclass);
    END IF;
    IF(currenttable<>tablename) THEN  
    currenttable=tablename;
     IF (progress_seq IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        RAISE NOTICE 'Columns left to look in: %; looking in table: %', currval(progress_seq::regclass), tablename;
        EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(''Current table (column ' || columnscount-currval(progress_seq::regclass) || ' of ' || columnscount || '): ' || tablename || '\n\nFound in tables/columns:\n' || COALESCE(
        (SELECT string_agg(c1 || '/' || c2, '\n') FROM (SELECT unnest(foundintables) AS c1,unnest(foundincolumns) AS c2) AS t1)
        , '') || ''',''\n''))) TO ''c:\WINDOWS\temp\' || progress_seq || '.txt''';
    END IF;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

-- Below function will list all the tables which contain a specific string in the database

```
 select TablesCount(‘StringToSearch’);
```

--Iterates through all the tables in the database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION **TablesCount**(_searchText TEXT)
RETURNS text AS 
$$ -- here start procedural part
   DECLARE _tname text;
   DECLARE cnt int;
   BEGIN
    FOR _tname IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' and table_type='BASE TABLE'  LOOP
         cnt= getMatchingCount(_tname,Columnames(_tname,_searchText));
                                RAISE NOTICE 'Count% ', CONCAT('  ',cnt,' Table name: ', _tname);
                END LOOP;
    RETURN _tname;
   END;
$$ -- here finish procedural part
LANGUAGE plpgsql; -- language specification
```

-- Returns the count of tables for which the condition is met.
-- For example, if the intended text exists in any of the fields of the table,
-- then the count will be greater than 0. We can find the notifications
-- in the Messages section of the result viewer in postgres database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION **getMatchingCount**(_tname TEXT, _clause TEXT)
RETURNS int AS 
$$
Declare outpt text;
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'Select Count(*) from '||_tname||' where '|| _clause
       INTO outpt;
       RETURN outpt;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

--Get the fields of each table. Builds the where clause with all columns of a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION **Columnames**(_tname text,st text)
RETURNS text AS 
$$ -- here start procedural part
DECLARE
                _name text;
                _helper text;
   BEGIN
                FOR _name IN SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.Columns WHERE table_name =_tname LOOP
                                _name=CONCAT('CAST(',_name,' as VarChar)',' like ','''%',st,'%''', ' OR ');
                                _helper= CONCAT(_helper,_name,' ');
                END LOOP;
                RETURN CONCAT(_helper, ' 1=2');

   END;
$$ -- here finish procedural part
LANGUAGE plpgsql; -- language specification
```

Answer (score -1):

To lookup a value somewhere in `Postgresql`

```
SELECT * FROM <SchemaName>.<TableName> WHERE <ColumnName> LIKE '<ValueYouLookFor>';
```