# How to count a number of substring in a row via SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database represeting a simple address book through MS Studio 2015 (C#) and MS SQL Server 2008. I successfully added 'insert row' and 'remove row' methods in my code. So I want to compose a query (a stored procedure) which counts a number of substring in every row.

For example, I have the database which includes a table called Contacts:

```
PersonID  Name       Surname   City       Phone
1         Alice      Karlsson  Gotheburg  69-58-12
2         Mark       Morrow    Stockholm  48-48-48
3         Katherine  Karlsson  Gotheburg  69-58-16
```

If I try to find and count 'th' in the table, I want to get the following the result:

```
PersonID  Name       Surname   City       Phone     Count
3         Katherine  Karlsson  Gotheburg  69-58-16  2
1         Alice      Karlsson  Gotheburg  69-58-12  1
```

So I don't know how to do that. I've been googling for all the day but I didn't find the satisfying result. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539873/search-all-columns-of-a-table-for-a-value) on the stackoverflow.com I find a solution returning the next result:

```
ColumnName     ColumnValue
Contacts.City  Gotheburg
Contacts.Name  Katherine
Contacts.City  Gotheburg
```

Please, give me any idea to compose a query returning the expected  result.

Full-text search; is the expected result

UPD: 'th' is a substring I'm looking for in a row. So it should count "Agathe', 'th' and 'youth' the same way.

Comment: what is 'th' that you want to count?

Comment: @jtr 'th' is a substring I'm looking for in a row.

Comment: Actually you should think up something different with fuzzy search support. If `like` fulfills your needs - build a column which is a combination of all values you need to search through.

Answer (score 1):

You should try following,

```
Select 
    PersonId,
    Name,
    Surname,
    City,
    Phone,
    sum(count) as count
From
(
    select 
        *,
        (Len(name) - LEN(REPLACE(name, 'th', ' ')) + 
        Len(surname) - LEN(REPLACE(surname, 'th', ' ')) + 
        Len(city) - LEN(REPLACE(city, 'th', ' '))) as count

    from Contacts 
    where name like '%th%' or surname like '%th%' or city like '%th%'
)T
Group by PersonId, Name, Surname, City, Phone
Order by 6 desc
```

Comment: If I have a name like 'Agathe-Katherine' it must count twice. But your algorythm count the name only one time. How to make it count the real number of 'th' in the field?

Comment: See I have replace core logic to find character occurrences in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you are trying to achieve is fulltext search...
Please follow this link..
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

create a full text index

and use this script

```
select * from yourtable
where freetext (*,'your_search_item')
```

Comment: I did that way. I created a fulltext catalog and index, after that I used the script above. So as a result of searching 'th' or '%th%' it returns nothing. When I search for a normal name 'Alice' it returns me a row containing this field. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select * from Contacts where Contacts.City like '%th%' or 
Contacts.Name like '%th%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table valued function that loops on all rows column by column to seek the sub-string with a counter, 
inside the loop you can use built in functions that help in seeking texts such as `CHARINDEX('th',Name+Surname+City,0)`

which gives the exact location of the sub-string inside the text ...