# Search in all tables in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In PgAdmin, is it possible to search for a value in ALL tables? In phpmyadmin this is possible and quite convenient. You search for an ID value and find all the tables in which it occurs. I can't seem to find this function in PgAdmin.

Does it exist?

Comment: It is not for PgAdmin, but maybe this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql

Comment: Thanks. That's quite cumbersome ... weird there is no solution for this, it' so useful.

Comment: Posted an answer, then looked at these comments. 1. No, it can easily be used from pgAdmin. 2. That's not cumbersome at all, it requires only Copy/Paste, then run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It currently doesn't exist in PgAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

There's custom function for this. You can use it from Query tool. See [[How to search a specific value in all tables (PostgreSQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql)
](as of today, there are two modifications in answers there that include column name, progress reporting)