# Search an specific record in all the tables with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, schema

I'm trying to obtain an specific value in all my schema. I found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql) but, are oriented in know column names, but my current problem is: I have an schema with 320 tables and some specific values to search in some(s) of these tables. Is possible do a similar search?

Comment: If this is a one-off requirement, you could make a database dump and search that. If it's a permanent feature, you might want to look at a separate indexing server, such as Solr or Xapian

Comment: Actually, looking at the linked question, I don't understand the difference between your question and that one.

Comment: Is a one time requirement, just now, i have listed all my table names with: `select * from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` , but, I am trying to search the content into of these tables. is possible?

Comment: @IMSoP in the reference link, finally, the queries are of specific tables like the last answer, I'm trying obtain for example the text `LIKE 'DTD%'` but, this text could be contained in X records in the tables in the schema.

Comment: The accepted answer shows a search across the whole database, with no foreknowledge of which tables or columns will show up in the output.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not totally sure, I mean, for example, how I can do something like:  `SELECT * from information_schema.X where x.x  = LIKE 'DTD%'` and display related records?

Comment: So to be clear you want to search column names in all tables?

Comment: I've replied in the duplicate with a function that's more useful for your problem than grep in dump: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23036421/238814