# Postgresql format() function alternative

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

Hi  My question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql)

But i haven't found any  answer there in that link.  I don't want any tool to acheive my requirement. I am looking for a simple procedure or query. In that link someone answered about search_columns() procedure. Right now i am using postgresql 9.0.4 version. Can some
Postgresql Guru over there can answer this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql)

Also Is there any alternative for format() function for 9.1 below versions. I see that the format() function is supported in postresql 9.1 versions and above. Can anybody tell me how to use format function or any alternative to format function for 9.0 or below versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5350405/330315

Answer (score 1):

On old versions you must instead use `quote_ident` and `quote_literal` with concatenation operations.

e.g.

```
format('SELECT %I FROM %I WHERE %I = %L', col1, tbl, col2, val)
```

becomes

```
'SELECT '||quote_ident(col1)||' FROM '||quote_ident(tbl)||' WHERE '||quote_ident(col2)||' = '||quote_nullable(val);
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but `%L` should be replaced by `quote_nullable()` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT