# Postgresql: Look For Some Text in Columns of a Table

Tags: postgresql, database-tools

I have a really peculiar problem.

I need to find a especific field in an old Postgresql database,
I know some values that is into this column but I don't know the table and column's name...

The problem is, there is no documentation of this database, and this database have more than 700 tables where some tables have 200 columns...

So I have more than 60.000 columns (in case of you use comma separator it's sixty thousand), we know that because of entity framework.

I have already looked through a lot of tables but I had no progres at all.

We need to find this because the business need to show the history data.

My question is: **Is there any tool that can look on each column of each table? Or is this even possible?**

OBS: I know that it would take a pretty long time to finish haha,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `COPY table TO 'C:\tmp\table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;` in a loop I was able to transform every table in a csv file and then I built and  ran a program to search on every file.

OBS: I did like that Because my version of Postgresql didn't support pg_dump.

For more information refer to [Export a PostgreSQL Table to a CSV](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/export-postgresql-table-to-csv-file/)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by running `pg_dump` to export the database in text format, then I would use `less` to search for the string in the file. Search backwards for the `COPY` statement to figure out the table.

Once you know the table, you can count the columns to find out in which column the value is stored.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I coundn't use pg_dump because the version of my postgres didn't support, but because of your comment I was able to create a loop and transform every table in a CSV file and then I ran a program to search on each file.