# How to create simple fuzzy search with PostgreSQL only?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I have a little problem with search functionality on my RoR based site. I have many Produts with some CODEs. This code can be any string like "AB-123-lHdfj". Now I use `ILIKE` operator to find products:

```
Product.where("code ILIKE ?", "%" + params[:search] + "%")
```

It works fine, but it can't find product with codes like "AB123-lHdfj", or "AB123lHdfj".

What should I do for this? May be Postgres has some string normalization function, or some other methods to help me?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Postgres provides a module with several string comparsion functions such as soundex and metaphone. But you will want to use the [levenshtein](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) edit distance function.

```
Example:

test=# SELECT levenshtein('GUMBO', 'GAMBOL');
 levenshtein
-------------
           2
(1 row)
```

The `2` is the edit distance between the two words. When you apply this against a number of words and sort by the edit distance result you will have the type of fuzzy matches that you're looking for.

Try this query sample: (with your own object names and data of course)

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
WHERE levenshtein(code, 'AB123-lHdfj') <= 3
ORDER BY levenshtein(code, 'AB123-lHdfj')
LIMIT 10
```

This query says:

Give me the top 10 results of all data from some_table where the edit distance between the code value and the input 'AB123-lHdfj' is less than 3. You will get back all rows where the value of code is within 3 characters difference to 'AB123-lHdfj'...

Note: if you get an error like:

```
function levenshtein(character varying, unknown) does not exist
```

Install the `fuzzystrmatch` extension using:

```
test=# CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

Comment: Can you please show me some simple example of this function using? I have no idea how it can help me :)

Comment: I added a simple, hard-coded query sample that should be enough to get you started. Don't forget to make sure that the fuzzystrmatch module is available to you: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/categories/57-fuzzystrmatch

Comment: Levenshtein is an expensive function, is this running Levenshtein twice per call?

Comment: @triunenature How many times it gets called will actually depend on the optimization. If the optimizer is smart enough it'll call once and cache the results. I should also point out that even if it isn't optimized that the call's complexity is linear and not exponential so the performance impact isn't nearly as bad.

Comment: Thanks for hint with need of installing `fuzzystrmatch` for using `levenshtein` in postgresql. It helped me to get rid of `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts`

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter mentions that levenshtein is quite slow and that it is better to use pg_trgm. Will this still be true when using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/indexes-expressional.html for levenshtein?

Comment: **NOTE!** there is a `levenshtein_less_equal()` as well!

It is an accelerated version of the Levenshtein function for use when only **small** **distances** are of interest. If the actual distance is less than or equal to max_d, then levenshtein_less_equal returns the correct distance; otherwise it returns some value greater than max_d. If max_d is negative then the behavior is the same as levenshtein.

`test=# SELECT levenshtein_less_equal('extensive', 'exhaustive',2);`

Answer (score 54):

Paul told you about [`levenshtein()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html#id-1.11.7.24.7). That's a very useful tool, but it's also very slow with big tables. It has to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from the search term for every single row. That's expensive and cannot use an index. The "accelerated" variant `levenshtein_less_equal()` is faster for long strings, but still slow without index support.

If your requirements are as **simple** as the example suggests, you can still use `LIKE`. Just replace any `-` in your search term with `%` in the `WHERE` clause. So instead of:

```
WHERE code ILIKE '%AB-123-lHdfj%'
```

Use:

```
WHERE code ILIKE '%AB%123%lHdfj%'
```

Or, dynamically:

```
WHERE code ILIKE '%' || replace('AB-123-lHdfj', '-', '%') || '%'
```

`%` in `LIKE` patterns stands for 0-n characters. Or use `_` for exactly one character. Or use regular expressions for a smarter match:

```
WHERE code ~* 'AB.?123.?lHdfj'
```

`.?` ... 0 or 1 characters

Or:

```
WHERE code ~* 'AB\-?123\-?lHdfj'
```

`\-?` ... 0 or 1 dashes

You may want to escape special characters in `LIKE` or regexp patterns. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

---

If your actual problem is **more complex** and you need something faster then there are various options, depending on your requirements:

- There is [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html), of course. But this may be an overkill in your case.
- A more likely candidate is trigram-matching with the additional module [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). See:

  - [Using Levenshtein function on each element in a tsvector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100983/using-levenshtein-function-on-each-element-in-a-tsvector/12101152#12101152)
  - [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
  - [Related blog post by Depesz](https://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/)

  Can be combined it with `LIKE`, `ILIKE`, `~`, or `~*` since PostgreSQL 9.1.
  Also interesting in this context: the `similarity()` function or `%` operator of that module.
- Last but not least you can implement a hand-knit solution with a function to **normalize** the strings to be searched. For instance, you could transform `AB1-23-lHdfj` --> `ab123lhdfj`, save it in an additional column and search with terms transformed the same way.

  Or use an [index on the expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) instead of the redundant column. (Involved functions must be `IMMUTABLE`.) Possibly combine that with `pg_tgrm` from above.

Overview of pattern-matching techniques:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)