# Using Levenshtein function on each element in a tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search, tsvector

I'm trying to create a fuzzy search using Postgres and have been using django-watson as a base search engine to work off of.

I have a field called search_tsv that its a tsvector containing all the field values of the model that I want to search on.

I was wanting to use the Levenshtein function, which does exactly what I want on a text field. However, I dont really know how to run it on each individual element of the tsvector.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It remains unclear what you are after. Add an example of what you want to get to make it clear. And add definitions of involved tables.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the extension `pg_trgm` instead of `levenshtein()`. It is faster by orders of magnitude when backed with a [GiST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPE-GIST) to support the [KNN feature in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#K-Nearest-Neighbor_Indexing).

Install the extension once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

And use the [`<->` or `%` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE). Several related answers have been posted here on SO. Search for [pg_tgrm [PostgreSQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pg_tgrm%20%5BPostgreSQL%5D) ...

---

Wild shot at what you may want:

```sql
WITH x AS (
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array(trim(strip(
      'fat:2,4 cat:3 rat:5A'::tsvector)::text, ''''), ''' ''')) AS val
    )                                     -- provide ts_vector, extract strings
    , y AS( SELECT 'brat'::text AS term)  -- provide term to match
SELECT val, term
     , (val <-> term) AS trg_dist         -- distance operator
     , levenshtein(val, term) AS lev_dist
FROM   x, y;
```

Returns:

```
 val | term | trg_dist | lev_dist
-----+------+----------+----------
 cat | brat |    0.875 |        2
 fat | brat |    0.875 |        2
 rat | brat | 0.714286 |        1
```