# Fuzzy string search in array with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

This is how I do fuzzy string search in postgresql:

```
select * from table where levenshtein(name, 'value') < 2;
```

But what can I do if the 'name' colum contains array?

P.S.: It is necessary to use index.  And this is the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Levenshtein function on each element in a tsvector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100983/using-levenshtein-function-on-each-element-in-a-tsvector)

Comment: You can use elastic search too!

Comment: I see two solutions: 1) unnest   2) second table, that emulates unnest.   Does unnest use index? What if there are many unnested array fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use unnest() over the array:

```
select  * from
(
    select unnest(name) as name_in_array, id from 
    (
    select 1 as id, ARRAY['value1','valu','lav'] as name
    union all
    select 2 as id, ARRAY['value2','orange','yellow'] as name
    )t1
) t2
where levenshtein(name_in_array, 'value') < 2;
```