# Redshift: Any ways to compute fuzzy string similarity / string edit distance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, edit-distance

In PSQL (which I believe Redshift is based), there are string similarity functions like `levenshtein` / `levenshtein_less_equal` [ http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html ]. These features don't seem to have made it into Redshift [ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/String_functions_header.html ]. Am I wrong, or has anyone made a creative query to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 7):

*Redshift* is based on *Postgres* 8.0, which is extremely old (and no longer supported), so they've diverged substantially over the years. The development version of *Postgres* is currently 9.4, and 8.x and 9.x versions of *Postgres* have some substantial differences and additions in 9.0 and up.

The `levenshtein` function is part of the `fuzzystrmatch` module that you linked above, and that module was introduced in *Postgres 8.3*, which is likely why it didn't make the cut for *Redshift* (and it apparently has not since been added).

Normally I would say your best bet would be to define a custom *PL/pgSQL* function to implement the *Levenshtein Distance* algorithm, but according to the [Redshift doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html), *User-defined functions and stored procedures* are one of the many major features of *Postgres* that *Redshift* does not support, so I think you're unfortunately out of luck on that front.

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use `LIKE` to achieve similar results. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7747765/3583500) for more info on that (note that some of the alternative suggestions in that answer, such as *full text* are also not supported in *Redshift*).

**Update, 2016-04-25**

It appears as though since I originally answered this question back in Oct. 2014, an ability to create *Python*-based [*User Defined Functions*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) (*UDF*s) has been added. This is not as ideal as being able to create a custom *Postgres* function inline (the doc lists an assortment of caveats for the *UDF*s), but should allow the *levenshtein distance* algorithm to be implemented in *Python* and processed within the context of a *Redshift* query.

*UDF*s in *Apache Hive*, a data warehousing project used in the *Hadoop* ecosystem, allows for user-defined functions in a similar manner (*Java* or *Python* based).