# Postgres query for cross-checking 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, similarity

I have two tables, already populated with data as follows :

`table1` data are citizens data, with fields:

```
uniqid  (a uniqueIP for person, like social sec num) 
first_name 
last_name
birthdate
address
```

`table2` with fields:

```
first_name 
last_name
birthdate
address
gender
healthinsurance_type
...
```

`table1` data and `table2` data come from different and separate agencies. Names from those tables could be typed differently, and so on.

`table1` is authoritative for names and ID. `table2` is what I need to work on, but there's no ID (`citizenID`).

Now I need each row in `table2` to get a `citizenid`, associated from `table1`, so that in the end I get `table2` with additional ID column, correctly associated with each person.

Something like search in `table1` for a person (a row in `table2`) where some conditions match, and if a record exists in `table1`, put the ID of that record to a column in `table2`.

But do it fast and for all rows.
row count of table1 is around 2 million.
row count of table2 is around 900.000

Comment: A computer could screw this up really efficiently.  basically you can't join those tables.  maybe you could create a third table that links the two together or add columns from one table to the other.

Comment: You forgot to provide data types and constraints. Provide (the relevant parts of) what you get from psql with `\d tbl`. And, as *always*, your version of Postgres. Plus, can there be duplicates on either side?

Comment: vresion 9.1
Table1:
uniqid : integer (11 digits) , pk
names : char, not null
birthdate : date, not null
address : char, not null

Table2:
names,address,gender, insutype : char, not null 
birthdate : date, not null

table1 data are from civil registry office. this is reference. No duplicates.

table2 data are list of proposed healthcare recipients,collected manually by officers on the field (minus citizen ID, unfortunately), and then should be submitted to ministry WITH citizen ID on each individual. 
So I need to put correct citizen ID on each person in table2 , using table1 as a reference

Comment: Please ***edit*** the question. That kind of information is hardly readable in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are the only one writing to these tables, so no concurrency conflicts.

#### Step 1

Add the ID column to `table2`, can be NULL for now:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN citizenid int; -- or whatever the type is
```

Consider an additional flag on `table1` to take row "off the market" cheaply on the other side, too:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN hasmatch boolean;
```

#### Step 2

Assuming there are no duplicates on either side. Else you need to do more.

#### Step 3

Update all rows in table2 with a **perfect, complete match**. Flag matching rows in `table1` right away, too. With a [**data-modifying CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```sql
WITH u2 AS (
   UPDATE table2 t2
   SET    citizenid = t1.uniqid  
   FROM   table1 t1
   WHERE  t1.hasmatch IS NULL   -- always with this condition
   AND    t2.citizenid IS NULL  -- always with this condition
   AND    t2.first_name = t1.first_name
   AND    t2.last_name  = t1.last_name
   AND    t2.birthdate  = t1.birthdate
   AND    t2.address    = t1.address
   RETURNING citizenid
   )
UPDATE table1 t1
SET    hasmatch = TRUE
FROM   u2
WHERE  t2.citizenid = u2.citizenid;
```

As soon as a row has its `citizenid` it's "off the market" on both sides.

#### Step 4

Check how many rows are left and start **softening predicates in baby steps** to keep false positives at bay by always trying the more likely match first. Think of a **systematic strategy** before you start this **cyclic process**. Analyze remaining rows to find systematic typos or similar clues.

Possible options for fuzzy matching of character type columns are:

```sql
lower(t2.address) = lower(t1.address)
t2.address ILIKE (t1.address || %) -- here % is a wilcard for LIKE pattern
t1.address ILIKE (t2.address || %)
lower(left(t2.address, 20)) = lower(left(t1.address, 20))
t2.address % t1.address  -- here % is the similarity operator
levenshtein(t2.address, t1.address) <= 3  -- *very* expensive, no index support
```

Etc.
The similarity operator `%` is provided by the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), which also provides trigram indexes to support `LIKE` and similarity matches. You will ***need* indexes** for fuzzy matching or your queries may take a *long* time.

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Consider partial indexes to remove rows from the index as soon as a match is found. Like:

```sql
CREATE INDEX t1_adr_gin_trgm_idx ON table1 USING gin (address gin_trgm_ops)
WHERE t1.hasmatch IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX t2_adr_gin_trgm_idx ON table2 USING gin (address gin_trgm_ops)
WHERE t2.citizenid IS NULL;
```

Etc.

You can fine tune the similarity threshold for the `%` operator with:

```
SELECT set_limit(0.8);
```

#### Step 5

A small percentage is going to remain unresolved. You can spend an increasing amount of time to assign them manually until you decide to discard the rest.

#### Step 6

Optional. When the process is finished, every row has a `citizenid`, which can now be set to `NOT NULL`, new rows must have a `citizenid`

More Details:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [How to create simple fuzzy search with PostgreSQL only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730027/how-to-create-simple-fuzzy-search-with-postgresql-only/7747765#7747765)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Erwin, Still relatively novice on CTE though.
I can see the direction.

Comment: @rifaiz: [Search for \[postgres\] data-modifying CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgres]+data-modifying+CTE), you'll find lots of examples and explanation. I also added a link to the manual above.