# Missing fuzzystringmatch extension pg admin

Tags: hibernate, hql

I had a problem recentley with the following output from java with hibernate trying to execute a query.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: la funzione levenshtein_less_equal(text, character varying, integer) non esiste
  Suggerimento: Nessuna funzione trovata con nome e tipi di argomenti forniti. Potrebbe essere necessario convertire i tipi esplicitamente.
  Posizione: 464
```

Sorry for the italian log for error, basically says that function doesn't exists with that kind of parameters. I checked on my functions on the DB and I had a function called:

```
levenshtein_less_equal(text, text, integer)
```

Now, first I don't understand why `query.setparameter` on java, which sets both the 1st and the 2nd argument of the function with a string would end up with such function call

```
levenshtein_less_equal(text, character varying, integer)
```

Both are strings but one is mapped to text and one to character varying??

Second I don't understand **why I solved this** by adding the **fuzzystrmatch** extension to the DB extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`levenshtein_less_equal(text, text, integer)` is a function to compare two strings in postgres, it's part of the Fuzzymatch module that contains functions to get the distance between strings see: [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/fuzzystrmatch.html), one of the ways to compare string is called the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

When you do `setParameter()`in Hibernate you indirectly trigger a string comparison, I don't see your data but I think your data has special characters, here is a link to a stack overflow question that disscusses the same problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730027/how-to-create-simple-fuzzy-search-with-postgresql-only).

So what is basically happening here is that Postgres is trying to get an approximation for the strings that it doesn't understand in order to get a match and it's using the Levenshtein Distance to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped finding the solution. Basically the thing that confused me the most was the fact that i had a function defined with those parameters but the system didn't manage to get it. I just realize that the SQL definition of that function was simply a reference to that module i was missing.