# Postgresql Fuzzy Search

Tags: postgresql

Forgive this general question. I have created a huge Fuzzy Search function in PostgreSQL that uses Similarity, Soundex, Metaphone, Levenshtein, and other types of logic comparisons. I've placed weighted values on each result. The function has grown to improve results, but it is slow and still not great! I've spent a lot of time researching and searching for a Fuzzy Search that someone has created who is smarter than me!

Does anyone know of a great fuzzy search function for PostgreSQL that compares two strings and produces a score that can be sorted? I am hoping for something that can work like:

SELECT tbl_name_column, fuzzy_function(tbl_name_column, 'Most like this string') as score
FROM tbl
ORDER BY score desc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create simple fuzzy search with PostgreSQL only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730027/how-to-create-simple-fuzzy-search-with-postgresql-only)

Answer (score 3):

The [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) extension provides Trigram scoring, but there's also the [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html) extension mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730094/12075411) that offers other algorithmic support (the current PG documentation [v14] warns that everything but the `levenshtein()` function doesn't work well with multibyte encodings like UTF-8, so user beware).

pg_trgm:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_name_column, 
    similarity(tbl_name_column, 'search string') AS score 
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY score DESC; -- Trigram score increases with similarity
```

fuzzystrmatch:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_name_column, 
    levenshtein(tbl_name_column, 'search string') AS score 
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY score ASC; --levenshtein distance decreases with similarity
```