# Get list of matching keywords for each post

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `keywords` and `posts` in my PieCloudDB Database.

Each topic can be expressed by one or more keywords. If a keyword of a certain topic exists in the content of a post (**case insensitive**) then the post has this topic.

For example:

| topic_id | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | basketball |
| 2 | music |
| 3 | food |
| 4 | war |

| post_id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A typhoon warning has been issued in southern Japan |
| 2 | We are going to play neither basketball nor volleyball |
| 3 | I am indulging in both the delightful music and delectable food |
| 4 | That basketball player fouled again |

Now I want to find the topics of each post according to the following rules:

- If the post does not have keywords from any topic, its topic should be "`Vague!`".
- If the post has at least one keyword of any topic, its topic should be a string of the IDs of its topics sorted in ascending order and separated by commas ','.

For the above example data, the results should be:

| post_id | topics |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vague! |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2,3 |
| 4 | 1 |

```
SELECT post_id, COALESCE(array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ','), 'Vague!') AS topic
FROM (
    SELECT p.post_id, k.topic_id
    FROM Posts p 
    LEFT JOIN Keywords k 
    ON LOWER(content) LIKE '% ' || keyword || ' %' OR content LIKE keyword || ' %' OR content LIKE '% ' || keyword
  ) a
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_id
```

I tried this query but the results I got were not exactly correct. I don't know why the output of post 1 is `null`:

| post_id | topics |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2,3 |
| 4 | 1 |

Can anyone give me a correct answer?
(If you don’t know the database I use, you can use PostgreSQL instead.)

Comment: Should a keyword "war" match the word "wars" in content? Are you dealing with English language words? This kind of query heavily depends on the definition of how to match exactly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple regex without index support

Without index support (only sensible for trivial cardinalities!) this is fastest in Postgres, while doing **exactly** what you ask for:

```sql
SELECT post_id, COALESCE(string_agg(topic_id::text, ',' ), 'Vague!') AS topic
FROM  (
   SELECT p.post_id, k.topic_id
   FROM   post p 
   LEFT   JOIN keyword k ON p.content ~* ('\m' || k.keyword || '\M')
   ORDER  BY p.post_id, k.topic_id
   ) sub
GROUP  BY post_id
ORDER  BY post_id;
```

`~*` is the case-insensitive regular-expression match operator. See:

- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336665/lower-like-vs-ilike/20337500#20337500)

Concerning my regex, I cite [the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

> `\m` ... matches only at the beginning of a word
> `\M` ... matches only at the end of a word

This covers the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string implicitly. `\W` (as suggested in another answer) matches any non-word character, and is wrong for the task.)

Note how I apply `ORDER BY` once in a subquery instead of per-aggregate, because that's faster. See:

- [How to combine ORDER BY and LIMIT with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213724/3684)

In this constellation, a simple `COALESCE` catches the case of no matches.

#### FTS index for strict matching

The simple (naive) approach above scales with O(N*M), i.e. terribly with a non-trivial number of rows in each table. Typically, you want index support.

While strictly matching keywords, the best index should be a **[Full Text Search index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX) with the `'simple'` dictionary**, and a query that can actually use that index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX post_content_fts_simple_idx ON post USING gin (to_tsvector('simple', content));


SELECT post_id, COALESCE(topics, 'Vague!') AS topics
FROM  (
   SELECT post_id, string_agg(topic_id::text, ',') AS topics
   FROM  (
      SELECT p.post_id, k.topic_id
      FROM   keyword k
      JOIN   post    p ON to_tsvector('simple', p.content) @@ to_tsquery('simple', k.keyword)
      ORDER  BY p.post_id, k.topic_id
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY post_id
   ) sub1
RIGHT  JOIN post p USING (post_id)
ORDER  BY post_id;
```

#### FTS index for matching English words

To match natural language words with built-in stemming, use a matching **dictionary, `'english'`** in the example:

```sql
CREATE INDEX post_content_fts_en_idx ON post USING gin (to_tsvector('english', content));

SELECT post_id, COALESCE(topics, 'Vague!') AS topics
FROM  (
   SELECT post_id, string_agg(topic_id::text, ',') AS topics
   FROM  (
      SELECT p.post_id, k.topic_id
      FROM   keyword k
      JOIN   post    p ON to_tsvector('english', p.content) @@ to_tsquery('english', k.keyword)
      ORDER  BY p.post_id, k.topic_id
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY post_id
   ) sub1
RIGHT  JOIN post p USING (post_id)
ORDER  BY post_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5YQwykLS)

For fuzzy matching consider a trigram index. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [How to create simple fuzzy search with PostgreSQL only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730027/how-to-create-simple-fuzzy-search-with-postgresql-only/7747765#7747765)

Related:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)

Answer (score 0):

You're not distinguishing between `NULL` and the empty string (`''`) - this first query shows you where the problem is, the second shows a solution (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WDSAz0zg)):

```
SELECT 
  post_id, 
  
  COALESCE
  (
    array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ','), 
    'Vague!'
  ) AS topic,

  LENGTH(array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ',')),

  LENGTH(NULL) AS "Length of NULL",  -- <<== LENGTH(NULL) is always NULL, and NOT zero 

  PG_TYPEOF(NULL) AS "Type of NULL",
  
  PG_TYPEOF
  (
    array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ',')
  )
FROM 
(
  SELECT p.post_id, k.topic_id
  FROM post p 
  LEFT JOIN keyword k 
    ON LOWER(content) LIKE '% ' || topic || ' %' 
    OR content LIKE topic || ' %' OR content LIKE '% ' || topic
) a
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_id;
```

Note the use of the [`PG_TYPEOF()`](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-get-the-column-type-using-pg_typeof-function-in-postgresql/) function ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-info.html)) - can be handy for debugging!

Result:

```
post_id topic length Length of NULL Type of NULL pg_typeof
      1     0                  null      unknown      text
      2     1      1           null      unknown      text
      3   2,3      3           null      unknown      text
      4     1      1           null      unknown      text
```

So, the correct approach is:

```
SELECT 
  post_id, 
  CASE
    WHEN
      (array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ',') IS NULL) 
        THEN 'Vague!'
    WHEN
      (array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ',') = '') 
        THEN 'Vague!'      
    ELSE
      array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT topic_id ORDER BY topic_id), ',')
  END AS topic
FROM 
(
  SELECT p.post_id, k.topic_id
  FROM post p 
  LEFT JOIN keyword k 
    ON LOWER(content) LIKE '% ' || topic || ' %' 
    OR content LIKE topic || ' %' OR content LIKE '% ' || topic
) a
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_id;
```

Result:

```
post_id    topic
      1   Vague!
      2        1
      3      2,3
      4        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query and just use `STRING_AGG`, so you get rid of your subquery. By the way, please take care to always put the table alias before the column name, not only sometimes.

```
SELECT 
  p.post_id, 
  COALESCE(STRING_AGG(k.topic_id::varchar,',' 
             ORDER BY k.topic_id), 
           'Vague!') AS topic
  FROM Posts p 
  LEFT JOIN Keywords k 
    ON LOWER(p.content) LIKE '% ' || k.keyword || ' %' 
       OR p.content LIKE k.keyword || ' %' 
       OR p.content LIKE '% ' || k.keyword
  GROUP BY p.post_id
  ORDER BY p.post_id;
```

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D-BqtPYo) with your data.

The fiddle also shows you could use `CASE` rather than `COALESCE` in your orignal query which would solve your issue too. The issue was `COALESCE` replaces `NULL` values, but you got an empty string, not `NULL`. Anyway, your previous query is far too complicated for your use case.

You might also be able to simplify those `LIKE` conditions and rather use a Regex approach. Since I don't use Pie DB and am not sure about regex functionality there, I leave this part up to you.

Comment: The `OR p.content LIKE k.keyword || ' %'   OR p.content LIKE '% ' || k.keyword`  is not needed, because `LIKE '% ' || k.keyword || ' %'` will already match  (tested here: https://dbfiddle.uk/H0VX3h-y )

Answer (score 0):

To match keywords more accurately, you can try to use `regex` on your pieclouddb database.(The following query was tested on PostgreSQL)

```
SELECT p.post_id,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(k.topic_id) = 0 THEN 'Vague!'
        ELSE STRING_AGG(DISTINCT k.topic_id::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY k.topic_id::TEXT)
    END AS topics
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN keywords k ON LOWER(p.content) ~* CONCAT('(^|\W)', LOWER(k.keyword), '(\W|$)')
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY p.post_id
```