# SELECT if string contains column value

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

```
Manufacturer
==========================
id            name      
--------------------------
1             Company Inc.
2             Google Test.
3             3M (UNITY) USA. INC.
4             CE EE
```

Say, I have a string *'Google Test. 1257 SCS RANDOM 31233DD'* and I want to find all rows in table `manufacturer` where ht `name` is part of the given string:

```
SELECT * FROM manufacturer
WHERE 'Google Test. 1257 SCS RANDOM 31233DD' ILIKE '%' || name || '%'
```

Correctly returns:

```
id            name      
--------------------------
2             Google Test.
```

But when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM manufacturer
WHERE '3dad QTICE EEN ' ILIKE  '%' || name || '%'
```

it returns:

```
id            name      
--------------------------
4             CE EE
```

I don't want partial matches like this. The `name` shall not match in the middle of a word. I tried `substring()`:

```
SELECT * from manufacturer
WHERE  SUBSTRING('Google Test. 1257 SCS RANDOM 31233DD' from name) != '';
```

But I get:

> ```
> ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
> ```

Unfortunately I don't have the exact spec to go off since I am querying this off external db. But from what I have seen, column is `varchar(256)`. All values are upper cased and use plain spaces. All start with either character or number and end with either number, char, or special character. Ex: *'CLEVLAND DRILL (GREEN)'*. There are special characters in the value, such as `,.()&/`

I am not really looking for efficiency as long as it doesn't take over 50ms to do one query.

As of right now, there are about 10000+ entries but it could def grow over time.

Comment: To get a precise answer, you have to give a precise definition of "word". Are words always separated by plain spaces? What about start / end? Dash? Other punctuation? Case sensitive? Numbers? Stemming? And then: is the table big and performance important? Then provide your version of Postgres, table definition, avg. string length, cardinality.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hi sorry about that. I added the spec as best as I could from my observation.

Answer (score 2):

One method with `LIKE` is to add spaces to the begining and end:

```
SELECT *
FROM db
WHERE ' ' || '3dad QTICE EEN ' || ' ' ILIKE  '% ' || manufacturer || ' %'
```

If you need more sophisticated matching, then you might need to use regular expressions with word boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you really need to use regex, as adding a space either side of the string will not match at the beginning or end of the line. By using regex, we can check for that situation too. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM manufacturer
WHERE 'Google Test. 1257 36700 SCS RANDOM WORD 31233DD' ~ ('(^| )' || name || '( |$)');
```

Output:

```
id  name
2   Google Test.
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM manufacturer
WHERE '3dad QTICE EEN ' ~ ('(^| )' || name || '( |$)');
```

Output:

```
There are no results to be displayed.
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM manufacturer
WHERE 'CE EE ' ~ ('(^| )' || name || '( |$)');
```

Output:

```
id  name
4   CE EE
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJZnDdo2kNxWSg4Lgbnedq/0)

**Update**

Because the `name` values in the table can contain characters that have special meaning in a regex, they need to be escaped before the name is included into the regex. You can do this with [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html) e.g.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '([\\.+*?[^\]$(){}=!<>|:\-#])', '\\\1', 'g')
```

So your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM manufacturer
WHERE 'Google Test. 1257 36700 SCS RANDOM WORD 31233DD' ~ ('(^| )' || REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '([\\.+*?[^\]$(){}=!<>|:\-#])', '\\\1', 'g') || '( |$)');
```

[Updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJZnDdo2kNxWSg4Lgbnedq/2)

Comment: so I tried using regex and I get an error 'ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid'. Could this be due to special char in the value? I added spec to my post. Thanks

Comment: @Av0id I've updated my answer to deal with that situation

Answer (score 2):

> All the values start with either character or a number and end with either number, char, or special character. ... There are special characters in the value, such as `,.()&/`.

I suggest the regular expression match operator **[~](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)**. Carefully define ***boundaries*** and ***escape special characters*** in `name`:

Create *once*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_regexp_escape(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT regexp_replace($1, '([!$()*+.:<=>?[\\\]^{|}-])', '\\\1', 'g')
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM manufacturer
WHERE  '3dad QTICE EEN ' ~ ('\m' || f_regexp_escape(name) || '( |$)')
```

#### How? Why?

`\m` .. [beginning of a word.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE) Works, since: *values start with either character or number*
`( |$)` .. a space or the end of the string. We need this since values: *end with either number, char, or special character*

The content of `manufacturer.name` is the core of the ***pattern***. You want the literal meaning of all its characters, so strip any special meaning by escaping properly. This is true for `LIKE` (few special characters) as well as the regular expression match operator `~` (more special characters). Often overlooked and quite a pitfall. That got you (and the tricky definition of bounds). Read this!

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

And then use the function `f_regexp_escape()` as demonstrated. A `name` like:

```
3M (UNITY) USA. INC.
```

becomes:

```
3M \(UNITY\) USA\. INC\.
```

Might be convenient to store readily escaped patterns in table `manufacturer`, maybe as additional column. And maybe with added padding like this:

```
\m3M \(UNITY\) USA\. INC\.( |$)
```

Or generate the pattern on the fly like demonstrated.

This way `name` can be a single word or a whole phrase, and end with any characters. But start and end never match in the middle of a "word" on the other side.

There is an arsenal of other pattern matching tools in Postgres:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

If your table is big, consider the ***[full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html)*** infrastructure with optimized indexes and ***phrase search*** capability:

- [How to search hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204601/3684)

Comment: I initially tried this approach (using `\m`, `\M` and also `\y`) but found it won't work where the table column ends (or starts) with a non-word character as there is then no word break to match against. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJZnDdo2kNxWSg4Lgbnedq/1

Comment: @Nick: Yes, a valid point. The OP really needs to clarify the specs.

Comment: I added spec to my post. Thanks

Comment: @Av0id: I adapted to those specs accordingly.