# Return first available row if initial SELECT finds nothing, in a single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to put together a SQL query that will return data based on a simple `WHERE` condition but will also return the first available record if the condition is not met.

| author_id | post_id | publish_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 | 2021-07-23 |
| 2 | 432 | 2021-06-22 |
| 2 | 555 | 2020-07-23 |

Using the data above my basic query would look like this

```
select *
from posts
where author_id = 1
and publish_date > '2021-07-01'
order by publish_date
```

Results, ie posts by the author published after a specified date

| author_id | post_id | publish_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 | 2021-07-23 |

Since author 2 has no posts after this date I would like it to return the most recent post of the specified author.
I want to be able to output "<*author*> hasn't posted since <*search_date*>, the most recent post was on <*publish_date*>" without querying the database multiple times.

Desired result for author_id 2 (who doesn't have any posts where publish_date > '2021-07-01')

| author_id | post_id | publish_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 432 | 2021-06-22 |

Is it possible to query for the first available record if the date condition is not met in a single statement?

Comment: Do you need to get those two records as two rows (with the same columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible with a single query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  author_id = 1
   AND    publish_date > '2021-07-01'
   ORDER  BY publish_date
   )
TABLE cte
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM cte)
AND    author_id = 1
AND    publish_date <= '2021-07-01'
ORDER  BY publish_date DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1
);
```

Related:

- [Combining 3 SELECT statements to output 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348755/combining-3-select-statements-to-output-1-table/59349080#59349080)

Or with a PL/pgSQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(_author_id int, _publish_date date)
  RETURNS SETOF posts
  LANGUAGE plpgsql aS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  author_id = _author_id
   AND    publish_date > _publish_date
   ORDER  BY publish_date;
   
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT *
      FROM   posts
      WHERE  author_id = _author_id
      AND    publish_date <= _publish_date
      ORDER  BY publish_date DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM my_func(2,'2021-07-01');
```

Related:

- [PLpgSQL function not returning matching titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040653/plpgsql-function-not-returning-matching-titles/67041419#67041419)
- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for this and get exactly what you want implementing conditions:

```
create or replace function some_func(input_author_id integer, input_date date)
    returns setof posts
as
$$
declare
    selected_posts posts%rowtype;
begin
    select * from posts p into selected_posts where p.author_id = input_author_id and p.publish_date > input_date;
    if not found then
        return query
        select * from posts p where p.author_id = input_author_id order by publish_date desc limit 1;
    else 
        return query
        select * from posts p where p.author_id = input_author_id and p.publish_date > input_date;
    end if;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

After that, just pass the values of the parameters you want:

```
select * from some_func(2,'2021-07-01');
```

And this will give you the below result:

| author_id | post_id | publish_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 432 | 2021-06-22 |