# Full text search returning too many irrelevant results and causing poor performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I'm using the full text search feature from Postgres and for the most part it works fine.

I have a column in my database table called `documentFts` that is basically the `ts_vector` version of the `body` field, which is a text column, and that's indexed with GIN index.

Here's my query:

```
select
      count(*) OVER() AS full_count,
      id,
      url, 
      (("urlScore" / 100) + ts_rank("documentFts", websearch_to_tsquery($4, $1))) as "finalScore",
      ts_headline(\'english_unaccent\', title, websearch_to_tsquery($4, $1)) as title,
      ts_headline(\'english_unaccent\', body, websearch_to_tsquery($4, $1)) as body,
      "possibleEncoding",
      "responseYear"
    from "Entries"
    where 
      "language" = $3 and 
      "documentFts" @@ websearch_to_tsquery($4, $1)
    order by (("urlScore" / 100) + ts_rank("documentFts", websearch_to_tsquery($4, $1))) desc limit 20 offset $2;
```

The dictionary is `english_unaccent` because I created one based on `english` that uses the `unaccent` extension by using:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english_unaccent (
  COPY = english
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english_unaccent
  ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word WITH unaccent,
  english_stem;
```

I did the same for other languages.

And then I did this to my Entries db:

```
ALTER TABLE "Entries"
  ADD COLUMN "documentFts" tsvector;

UPDATE
  "Entries"
SET
  "documentFts" = (setweight(to_tsvector('english_unaccent', coalesce(title)), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('english_unaccent', coalesce(body)), 'C'))
WHERE
  "language" = 'english';
```

I have a column in my table with the language of the entry, hence the `"language" = 'english'`.

So, the problem I'm having is that for words like `animal`, `anime` or `animation`, they all go into the vector as `anim`, which means that if I search for any of those words I get results with all of those variations.

That returns a HUGE dataset that causes the query to be quite slow compared to searches that return fewer items. And also, if I search for `Anime`, my first results contain `Animal`, `Animated` and the first result that has the word `Anime` is the 12th one.

Shouldn't `animation` be transformed to `animat` in the vector and `animal` just be `animal` as the other variations for it are `animals` or `animalia`?

I've been searching for a solution to this without much luck, is there any way I can improve this, I'm happy to install extensions, reindex the column or whatever.

Comment: Did you try changing snowball stemmer to ispell stemmer?  How about using a PostgreSQL synonym dictionary, which let's you override stemming for specific words?

Comment: I'll give it a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many little details to this. The best solution depends on the exact situation and exact requirements.

Two simple options:

#### Simple tweak 1

If you want to sort rows where `title` or `body` have a word starting with 'Anime' (exactly) in it, matched case-insensitively, add an `ORDER BY` expression like:

```sql
ORDER  BY unaccent(concat_ws(' ', title, body) !~* ('\m' || f_regexp_escape($4))
        , (("urlScore" / 100) + ts_rank("documentFts", websearch_to_tsquery($4, $1))) DESC
```

Where the auxiliary function `f_regexp_escape()` escapes special regexp characters and is defined here:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

That expression is rather expensive, but since it's only applied to filtered results, the effect is limited.
You may have to fine-tune, as other search terms present other difficulties. Think of 'body' / 'bodies' stemming to 'bodi' ...

#### Simple tweak 2

To remove English stemming completely, base yours on the 'simple' `TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION`:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_unaccent (
  COPY = simple
);
```

Etc.

Then the actual language of the text is irrelevant.The index gets substantially bigger, and the search is done on literal spellings. You can now widen the search with **prefix matching** like:

```
WHERE  "documentFts" @@ to_tsquery('simple_unaccent', ($1 || ':*')
```

Again, you'll have to fine-tune. The simple example only works for single-word patterns. And I doubt you want to get rid of stemming altogether. Probably too radical.

See:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)

### Proper solution: Synonym dictionary

You need access to the installation drive of the Postgres server for this. So typically not possible with most hosted services.

To overrule some of the stemmer decisions, overrule with your own set of synonym(rule)s. Create a mapping file in `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/my_synonyms.syn`. That's `/usr/share/postgresql/13/tsearch_data/my_synonyms.syn` in my Linux installation:

Let it contain (case insensitive by default):

```
anime anime
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY my_synonym (
    TEMPLATE = synonym,
    SYNONYMS = my_synonyms
);
```

There is a chapter with [instructions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY). One quote:

> A synonym dictionary can be used to overcome linguistic problems, for example, to prevent an English stemmer dictionary from reducing the word “Paris” to “pari”. It is enough to have a `Paris paris` line in the synonym dictionary and put it before the `english_stem` dictionary.

Then:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_english_unaccent (
  COPY = english
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION my_english_unaccent
  ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
  WITH unaccent, my_synonym, english_stem;   -- added my_synonym!
```

You have to update your column `"documentFts"` with `my_english_unaccent`. While being at it, use a proper lower-case column name like `document_fts`, and consider a `GENERATED` column. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Now, searching for `Anime` (or `ánime`, for that matter) won't find `animal` any more. And searching for `animal` won't find `Anime`.

Comment: I like the last option, I'm using a vps with docker. So I can do all of that. My question is, do I have to create this dictionary myself or is there a place I can download ready made dictionaries?
I would also need to do that for other languages like portuguese, spanish, german, italian, french and so on, most of which I don't speak.

Comment: @Eric.M: I am not aware of any public "library" of such dictionaries. Doesn't mean there are none ...