# SQL Using LIKE and ANY at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I have a table with a column `feature` of type `text` and a text array (`text[]`) named `args`. I need to select from the table those rows in which the **`feature`** column contains at least one of the elements of the **`args`** array.

I've tried different options, including this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE feature LIKE '%' + ANY (args) + '%';
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to use the regular expression match operator `~` instead, which works with strings in `arg` as is (without concatenating wildcards):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  feature ~ ANY(args);
```

`string ~ 'pattern'` is mostly equivalent to `string LIKE '%pattern%'`, but not *exactly*, as `LIKE` uses different (and fewer) special characters than `~`. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

If that subtle difference is not acceptable, here is an *exact* implementation of what you are asking for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  t.feature LIKE ANY (SELECT '%' || a || '%' FROM unnest(t.args) a);
```

Unnest the array, pad each element with wildcards, and use `LIKE ANY` with the resulting set.

See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)