# Is it valid to use LIKE with IN in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Does it work to use something like

```
LIKE IN ('%John%', '%Bob%', '%Sean%')
```

to exclude records which contain these symbols

For example this can be a possible solution but it doesn't work

```
'John S' or a varchar field NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY[cast(:listOrArrayOfExcludedNames AS text)])
```

I've found out that this solution works

```
'John S' or a varchar field !~ 'John|Bob|Sean'
```

to exclude records with regex. It's worth mentioning that I use native query.

Anyway, does it work to pass array or list to DATA JPA method to exclude records which contains values from array or list?

Comment: I would use `!~ 'John|Bob|Sean'` and write a wrapper method that accepts a collection of name parts and converts them to `"John|Bob|Sean"` which is then passed to a [custom JPA method](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

Comment: *"to exclude records which contain these symbols"* ... contain any of these strings or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

This is just invalid syntax:

```
... LIKE IN ('%John%', '%Bob%', '%Sean%')
```

This would be valid:

```sql
... LIKE ANY ('{%John%, %Bob%, %Sean%}')
```

But the regular expression operator `~` or its negation `!~` is simpler for the use case.

To exclude all rows where `varchar_field` contains any of the given strings:

```sql
... WHERE varchar_field !~ ALL ('{John,Bob,Sean}')
```

Or:

```sql
... WHERE varchar_field !~ ALL (:array_of_strings)
```

A Postgres array literal looks like this:

```sql
'{John,Bob,Sean}'
```

Note that a `null` value in `varchar_field` does not qualify because the expression evaluates to `null` in this case, and only `true` passes a `WHERE` condition.

Unlike `LIKE`, the regular expression operators don't require leading and trailing wildcards for this (non-)match.
See:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)
- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause/31192557#31192557)
- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)
- [SQL Using LIKE and ANY at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517587/sql-using-like-and-any-at-the-same-time/69517675#69517675)