# Can't fit regexp for a substring

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have to find and remove a substring from the text using regexp in PostgreSQL. The substring corresponds to the condition: <any text between double-quotes containing *for|while* inside>

**Example**

Text:

```
PERFORM xxkkcsort.f_write_log("INFO", "xxkkcsort.f_load_tables__outof_order_system", "   Script for data loading: ", false, v_sql, 0);
```

So, my purpose is to find and remove the substring "Script for data loading: ".
When I tried to use the script below:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
   'PERFORM xxkkcsort.f_write_log("INFO", "xxkkcsort.f_load_tables__outof_order_system", "> Table for loading: "||cc.source_table_name , false, null::text, 0);'
 , '(\")(.*(for|while)(\s).*)(\")'
 , '');
```

I have all the texts inside double-quotes replaced. The result looks like:

```
PERFORM xxkkcsort.f_write_log(||cc.source_table_name , false, null::text, 0);
```

What's a proper regular expression to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You canuse

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(
   'PERFORM xxkkcsort.f_write_log("INFO", "xxkkcsort.f_load_tables__outof_order_system", "> Table for loading: "||cc.source_table_name , false, null::text, 0);',
   '"[^"]*(for|while)\s[^"]*"',
   '') AS Result;
```

Output:

```js
PERFORM xxkkcsort.f_write_log("INFO", "xxkkcsort.f_load_tables__outof_order_system", ||cc.source_table_name , false, null::text, 0);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/owQQ26/1) and the [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bee6a66ee094a0c5d07e41f933ff6d1d). *Details*:

- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `(for|while)` - `for` or `while`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[^"]*"` - zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char.

Answer (score 1):

> any text between double-quotes containing *for|while* inside

```
SELECT regexp_replace(string, '"[^"]*\m(?:for|while)\M[^"]*"', '');
```

`"` ... literal `"` (no special meaning here, so no need to escape it)

`[^"]*` ... character class including all characters except `"`, 0-n times

`\m` ... [beginning of a word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

`(?:for|while)` ... two branches in [non-capturing parentheses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE)
(`regexp_replace()` works with simple capturing parentheses, too, but it's cheaper this way since you don't use the captured substring. But try either with the replacement `'\1'`, where it makes a difference ...)

`\M` ... [end of a word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

`[^"]*` ... like above

`"` ... like above

I dropped [`\s`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) from your expression, as the task description does not strictly require a white-space character (end of string or punctuation delimiting the word ...).

Related:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)