# How to have a whole string as a normal string in PostgreSQL's regular match?

Tags: json, postgresql

In my sql code, I receive a input string as a regular match's filter, I want to have the whole string as a normal string, even it includes some special characters.

Just look below:

```
do $$ declare 
    jdata jsonb='[{"name":"Dog 3*240+1*120"}]'::jsonb;
    vfilter1 text='dog';
    vfilter2 text='3*240+1*120';
    vexists bool=false;
begin 
    select jdata @? concat('$[*] ? (@.name like_regex "',vfilter1,'" flag "i")')::jsonpath into vexists;
    raise notice 'exists:%',vexists; --the result is true
    select jdata @? concat('$[*] ? (@.name like_regex "',vfilter2,'" flag "i")')::jsonpath into vexists;
    raise notice 'exists:%',vexists;-- the result is false
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

[image: the sql code]

the string `3*240+1*120`  include `+` and `*` characters, perhaps this causes the regular match have them as special character. In my code, I just want to have the whole `vfilter` string includes all special characters together as a normal string for the regular match.

What should I do?

Comment: Why are you using like_regex or anything related to regex?

Comment: Because the json structure is nested, that is, the array is contains in another array, use like_regex, I can judge easily by jsonpath $.array1[*].array2[*] ? (@.key like_regex "xxx").

Comment: "*perhaps this causes the regular match have them as special character*" - yes it does. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5144036/1048572) for a solution. Also use `to_json()` to get a json string from text, not concatenation with `"`.

Comment: I tried `select '[{"name":"Dog 3*240+1*120"}]'::jsonb @? '$[*] ? (@.name like_regex "3\*240\+1\*120" flag "i")'`, returns false. Why? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS) for the feature you are using.

> The optional flag string may include one or more of the characters i
> for case-insensitive match, m to allow ^ and $ to match at newlines, s
> to allow . to match a newline, and **q to quote the whole pattern
> (reducing the behavior to a simple substring match)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my trouble. You are really warm-hearted and professional, Thanks!