# Return rows where array column has match for every pattern in given array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have the following table:

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id ║                 value                  ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ ['friend', 'apple', 'cat']             ║
║  2 ║ ['cat', 'friend', 'dog']               ║
║  3 ║ ['pasta', 'best-friend', 'lizard']     ║
║  4 ║ ['wildcat', 'potato', 'alices-friend'] ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

My goal is to return all rows where `value` contains a given array. For example:

1. `['friend', 'cat']` should return rows `1` and `2`.
2. `['%friend%', '%cat%']` should return rows `1`, `2` and `4`.

Currently I'm using this command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, value
FROM table
WHERE value @> (ARRAY['friend', 'cat']::VARCHAR[]);
```

But it's not working for example 2 listed above, when `(array['%friend%', '%cat%']::varchar[])`.

As it works for example 1, I think the problem is with the `%` symbols, but I don't know how to handle this, since I don't need to explicitly match the values.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=754eaf00bf49ce5448840873f983610a)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Are all of the values in your array distinct? How are you enforcing this? Could I have `4, ['cat', 'friend', 'dog', 'cat', 'friend']`?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW Yes, they're distinct. I'm enforcing this by manually adding the values, since it's a small table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a match in the array column `value` for ***every*** `LIKE` pattern in the given array of matches.

This query is tricky for two main reasons:

1. There is no [array operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) to compare a whole array to an array of `LIKE` patterns. (No "array contains" operator with pattern-matching.) The array column must be unnested.
2. It's not enough to simply count matches after unnesting, as one pattern can match multiple times, masking the absence of matches for another.

Rephrase the task like this:

*"Return all rows where none of the input patterns fails to find a match."*

This query implements it, as efficiently as possible:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.value
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM unnest('{%friend%, %cat%}'::text[]) AS p(pattern)
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM unnest(t.value) AS a(elem)
      WHERE  a.elem LIKE p.pattern
      )
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=031c8b71de321c47da35e9c656709ff5)*

Unfortunately, **no index support possible**. You'd have to normalize your relational design to allow that - with a many-to-one table replacing the array `value`.

#### Asides

Either way, to optimize performance, **fork two distinct cases**: search with and without special `LIKE` characters. Just check for the existence of characters with special meaning, i.e. one of `\%_`. Related:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

Your simple query can deal with plain equality - after sanitizing it:

```sql
SELECT id, value
FROM   tbl
WHERE  value @> '{friend, cat}';
```

`DISTINCT(id), value` was just a misleading, equivalent syntax variant of `DISTINCT id, value`. Are you confusing this with `DISTINCT ON`? See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

And, assuming `id` is the PK, then `DISTINCT` is just an expensive no-op in the given query. Remove it.

Finally, use `text[]` rather than `varchar[]`. There are corner cases where `text[]` is superior, `text` being the ["preferred" string type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html). See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)
- [PostgreSQL ignores index, runs seq scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/305636/3684)