# How to match a superstring in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like, matching

I have a column of words whose elements look like this:

```
id | word
---+---------
1  | cute
2  | advanced
3  | unusual
```

Suppose I want to run a query for the words "cuter" or "cutest." I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word% LIKE 'cutest'
```

Of course, I realize that's not valid SQL syntax, but I want to match a superstring, not a substring.

I don't want to use the similarity package because it will match things like "notcute", whereas I only want to specify that the wildcard should go at the *end* of the field.

Is this possible to achieve in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern goes to the right of `LIKE`. So:

```sql
SELECT * FROM words
WHERE 'cutest' LIKE word || '%'
AND    word Like 'cute%';
```

I added another `WHERE` condition to eliminate false positives on words like 'cut' or just 'c'. Also, this can (and typically will) still use an index, while the expression `'cutest' LIKE word || '%'` absolutely cannot.

Note that 'cuter' doesn't qualify. Your question is a bit inconsistent there.

See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

To treat special characters in your words as non-special, you'll have to escape accordingly. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)