# how to get characters between [ ] in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, substring, between, regexp-replace

I want get characters between [] from a string

example:

```
"hello" and "world"
```

from

```
"gegerferf[hello] frfer [world] frfre rfrf"
```

into a table

i am try with substring and for loop but i dont now.

```
select regexp_replace(string, '...','', 'g')
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

The question didn't provide an example of the expected results, so I'll present a couple of options.

The following is run to setup the demonstration context:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id serial primary key,
  string text
);

INSERT INTO t(string)
VALUES ('gegerferf[hello] frfer [world] frfre rfrf');
```

This query returns the text between brackets concatenated into a single string:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(string, '[^[]*\[([^]]*)\][^[]*', '\1', 'g')
  FROM t;
```

The result is:

```
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 helloworld
(1 row)
```

This query returns the text between brackets as separate rows:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(string, '\[([^]]*)\]', 'g'))[1]
  FROM t;
```

The output is:

```
 regexp_matches 
----------------
 hello
 world
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT  (REGEXP_MATCHES('gegerferf[hello] frfer [world] frfre rfrf','(?:\[)(.*?)(?:\])','g'))[1];
```

- `.*` (dot asterisk) by default is greedy, you need non-greedy, so use left Parentheses dot asterisk right Parentheses `(.*?)`
- you need escape brackets `[]`, see post here: [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns)
- you don't want capturing brackets `[]`, so you need non-capturing. see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html
  so you need `(?:re)`
- `SETOF text[]` is output data types for regexp_matches, so you need do array subscript in the end.