# How to match length of field in like search in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

Hi I have a following query where `conclusion_number` column may include `expertize_number` with additional text. Thus I'm trying to find `conclusion_number`  inside `expertize_number` via LIKE operator. However problem I'm facing is records starting with lesser or more characters in `conclusion_number` are also included, but I need to find only records where they match exactly the same. Is it possible to get length of `a.conclusion_number` used in like operator and compare it to length of `rg.expertize_number`? Thank you.

```
SELECT rg.task_id, a.id, a.conclusion_number, a.expertize_number, rg.id
From registration rg
         JOIN audit a on rg.expertize_number like '%' || a.conclusion_number || '%'
WHERE rg.task_id = '23402928';
```

Here as you can see many matches the only one I need is, like it's emphasized where conclusion_number matches expertize number both in value and length. Like in image conclusion_number is 132736 and length is 6 so it should match substring in expertize number and return this record.

Column data types are varchar (except for ids) as it may include alphanumeric values.

[image]

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: `on rg.expertize_number = a.conclusion_number` maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface it doesn't give expected result because expertize_number includes additional text. conclusion_number must match substring of expertize_number

Comment: So i'm confused what you want. Do you or don't you want to match a substring? Substrings are by definition not the exact length of the source. Please show an example of what you wanto to match and what you don't want to match, as text not images.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE(rg.expertize_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '', 'g') = REGEXP_REPLACE(a.conclusion_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '', 'g')` help you?

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I need to find only records where they match exactly the same.

So simply use the equality operator `=`:

```sql
SELECT rg.task_id, a.id, rg.expertize_number, rg.id
FROM   registration rg
JOIN   audit a ON rg.expertize_number = a.conclusion_number
WHERE  rg.task_id = 23402928;
```

If you are bound to the `LIKE` operator (construct, really) for some odd reason, use a pattern without wildcards:

```
JOIN   audit a ON rg.expertize_number LIKE a.conclusion_number
```

Make sure the pattern does not include wildcards. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)